# What do members of the Momo tribe carry inside their belt flasks?

Tags: arthdal-chronicles

S01E13 of *Arthdal Chronicles* introduces the Momo tribe, known for their navigational prowesses and their combat skills. Shortly before going to sleep, Eunseom asks Ipsaeng about the "water flasks" that all Momo tribe members carry on their belts, to which Ipsaeng scoffs and replies that "it's not a water flask, you moron".

Obviously this recipient is of some importance, since it's worn by everyone while seeming quite cumbersome (and possibly heavy). Judging by Ipsaeng's reaction, it's probably not something as mundane as a water flask or belt bag.

I thought it may be some kind of float artifact, but after watching the Xabara and her soldiers save Eunseom from the waterfall, I don't think they'd need it:

- Sateunik did say that Momo tribe members were different than Sarams when underwater
- and indeed, these guys own the place and certainly don't require any help.

**What is it then?**

---

I tried Googling variations of this question's title, but didn't find anything interesting; although I could only browse English-language results (maybe there's an answer in Korean interviews?). I also don't think this falls under the "future works" policy, as it doesn't look like it will be a tremendous plot point in season 2; especially since the Momo tribe went away after the Xabara settled her debt to Eunseom.